# pandas mean() value giving blanks

Tags: python, pandas

I have df3:

```
                                  1     2    3
A    Battery Voltage, V (Avg)     12    13   14
A    Max Watt, W                  4     5    10
A    Battery Temperature, C       20    21   22
```

I am trying to add a new column:

```
M = ['Battery Voltage, V (Avg)', 'Battery Temperature, C']

df3['Total/Max/Min'] = np.where(mask3, df3.mean(axis=1), df3.sum(axis=1))
```

but I am getting blank for the "mean" values"

```
                                  1     2    3     Total/Max/Min
A    Battery Voltage, V (Avg)     12    13   14                   <--
A    Max Watt, W                  4     5    10        19
A    Battery Temperature, C       20    21   22                   <--
```

EDIT:
the `type` for these two rows is `string`, even though the values are all numeric. I can't seem to convert to float()

EDIT2:
Actual df:

```
                                           1           2     3        4
CU0111-023349-J Output Energy, (Wh/h)      3.825    1.46    1.57    1.997
CU0111-023349-J Lights (Wh)                 1.53    1.46    1.57    1.997
CU0111-023349-J Lights+Media (Wh)           2.295   0         0       0
CU0111-023349-J Total Usage (h)             1       1         1       1
CU0111-023349-J Lights (h)                  0.4     1         1       1
CU0111-023349-J Light+Media (h)             0.6     0         0       0
CU0111-023349-J Battery Voltage, V (Max)    12.525  12.51   12.502  12.479
CU0111-023349-J Battery Voltage, V (Min)    12.44   12.467  12.421  12.409
CU0111-023349-J Battery Voltage, V (Avg)    12.463  12.494  12.484  12.454
CU0111-023349-J Max Watt, W                 5.213   2.784   3.723   3.615
CU0111-023349-J Battery Temperature, C      19.555  18.977  18.324  17.753
CU0111-023349-J Charge Energy, Wh/h         0.016   0.006   0.009   0.01
CU0111-023349-J Time of Full Charge         11:21
```

actual code:

```
L = ['Battery Voltage, V (Max)','Max Watt, W']
M = ['Battery Voltage, V (Avg)','Battery Temperature, C']
mask1 = df3.index.get_level_values(1).isin(L)
mask3 = df3.index.get_level_values(1).isin(M)
mask2 = df3.index.get_level_values(1) == 'Battery Voltage, V (Min)'
df3['Total/Max/Min'] = np.where(mask1, df3.max(axis=1),np.where(mask2, df3.min(axis=1),np.where(mask3, df3.median(axis=1), df3.sum(axis=1))))
result:
```

Comment: Could you not do `df['Total']=df['1']+df['2']+df['3']`?

Comment: the df is actually much bigger than what i have shown....

Comment: Please make a full [mcve].  Your code worked when I filled in the missing pieces, and I got a column [13.0, 19.0, 21.0].  (Aside: Total/Max/Min is a bad name for a column which contains sums and means.)

Comment: See EDIT. I can't make the example any more simpler than what it is I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** converting all columns to numeric dtypes:

```
df3 = df3.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

---

I can't reproduce your issue:

```
In [182]: df3
Out[182]:
                             1   2   3
A Battery Voltage, V (Avg)  12  13  14
  Max Watt, W                4   5  10
  Battery Temperature, C    20  21  22

In [183]: mask3
Out[183]: [True, True, False]

In [184]: df3['Total/Max/Min'] = np.where(mask3, df3.mean(axis=1), df3.sum(axis=1))

In [185]: df3
Out[185]:
                             1   2   3  Total/Max/Min
A Battery Voltage, V (Avg)  12  13  14      13.000000
  Max Watt, W                4   5  10       6.333333
  Battery Temperature, C    20  21  22      63.000000
```

Can you provide a reproducible data set?

Comment: see EDIT2. it recongises the mask, but just doesn't want to do `mean` on it. It can do `min`, `max`, and `sum`...

Comment: @wazzahenry, please provide an output of: `print(df.dtypes)` - i guess you have object/string dtypes instead of numeric ones

Comment: that works, but the 'Time of Full Charge' values disappear. Is there a way to exclude this row from the change?

Comment: @wazzahenry, from the change??

Comment: sorry, is there a way to exclude the 'Time of Full Charge' row from being converted from `object` to `numeric`?

Comment: @wazzahenry, i don't think so. Pandas has one dtype for the whole column. So if you have at least one non-numerical value in the column the whole column will be of `object` (string) dtype

Comment: @wazzahenry, you can convert your chargetime to # of minutes/seconds and then convert it to numerical dtype

Comment: @MaxuU, great, I just took out the ` : ` in the time values. will have to do